# Jquery Mobile $(document).on('pagecontainershow') & $.mobile.changePage()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

The issue I am having is when I am navigating between pages from the main menu page.  If I navigate to 2-3 pages too quickly, the new page appears for about half a second before the page shifts back to the previous page then about half a second later it finally goes back to the page referenced in $.mobile.changePage();  For instance, from the menu page, click on the link to go to page 1, then really fast click on the button to go back to the menu page.  After a few times of clicking quickly, page 1 will turn into the menu for half a second, turn back into page 1 for half a second then finally reload the menu page. I realize that in the real world most users won't navigate like this but I can't have a bug like this present as it can cause problems with loading form data.  Would that be causing the issue?

Comment: Come back to my blog if you still need a solution. I have fixed your code, and this is not a right place to talk about changes.

Comment: Your blog gives 404 for this topic- I'm also looking for more details to his problem.